# How to kill activity or call finish() from Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

I have the following code:

```
public void promptUserToSaveModifications() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.str_desea_guardar_antes_salir))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.msj_si), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (valoresGenerales.options.op_timer_oper_edicion_ot == 1 && valoresGenerales.options.Edi_bas_ot_RegistroHoper_boton_ini_ter_trabajo == 0) {
                        promptUserToFinishCurrentJob();
                    } else if (btnMnHoraInicioRegistroHoper.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.str_edit_correctivo_finalizar_trabajo))){
                        promptUserToFinishCurrentJob();
                    } else if (saveModifications()) {
                        if (!postProcessSave())
                            finish();
                    }
                }
            }).show();
}
private void promptUserToFinishCurrentJob() {

    if (existsCurrentJob()) {
        exist_inicio_hoper = true;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.str_trabajos_iniciados))

                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.msj_si), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                        toggleCurrentJob();

                        if (saveModifications()) {
                            if (!postProcessSave())
                                finish();
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    }
}

    @Override
public void finish() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("index", getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0));
    i.putExtra("top", getIntent().getIntExtra("top", 0));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    super.finish();
}
```

The thing is that if it enters into the `saveModifications()` by the second `else if` in the `promptUserTosaveModifications()` method, it does finish the activity. But, if by the first `else if` it enters into `promptUserToFinishCurrentJob()` and inside this one it enters into `saveModifications()`,, it doesn't finish the activity... do you know why and how can I finish it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing one condition . You need to put a else part too .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the activity context to finish an activity.
try

```
getApplicationContext().finish();
```

or

```
this.finish();
```

if you want to finish activity from an alert dialog in fragment the use

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: but I already override the finish method of the activity (now is displayed above, in the code of the post)

Comment: is still not working..

Comment: Use debugger to find the value returned by `postProcessSave()`. It must be returning true, so `finish()` is not executed.

Comment: thanks, I don't know why Studio was notifying me the value returned was 'false' but actually was 'true', and I spent so long to noticed that

Answer (score 2):

Always use `YourActivity.this.finish()` in async method.

Comment: it helps in my case, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the dialog i.e you need to get the activity first to finish it. Use the following to finish your activity.

```
getActivity().finish();
```