# Android activity crushes when the finish() is called after custom dialog dismiss()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, customdialog

With Kotlin, I'm using a custom dialog class. The activity need to be closed to return the previous activity with calling `finish()` of the activity on the `onClick()` of the dialog.

The simplified custom dialog

```kotlin
class TestDialog (context: Context) : Dialog(context),
    View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_result_screen)


        var yesButton=  findViewById(R.id.buttonControl);

        yesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        dismiss()
        (context as AppCompatActivity).finish()
    }
}
```

The activity call this dialog as

```kotlin
 val testDialog = TestDialog(this@TheDialogDisplayerActivity)
 testDialog.show()
 //used to dislay in full size of the secreen.
 val window: Window? = testDialog.window
 window?.setLayout(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

The activity is extending the `AppCompatActivity`

When the `finish()` is called, the following error is occurred that I've couldn't find a solution.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.xyz.widget.TestResultDialog.onClick(TestResultDialog.kt:67)
```

I've tried casting into activity class, too. This didn't work, either.

I've looked at these Q/As [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22477551/1820553), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49193094/1820553), and some other questions, too, but failed to resolve.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look in the parent class `Dialog` then the `context` becomes : `mContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId);` - which is exactly the error it is giving you when you try and cast it back to an `Activity` later.

You should do :

```
class TestDialog (private val activity: Activity) : Dialog(activity),
    View.OnClickListener {

  ...

  override fun onClick(v: View) {
        dismiss()
        activity.finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it recommended to explicitly call `finish()` in an Android app?  Or is it better to use Intents.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - depends.  If I want to, for example go from a splash screen onto another Activity I would use intent flags to start a new task, and not explcitly call `Activity::finish`. If I want to finish the activity I would call it - its all about usecase. However the OP's question/problem was a `ClassCastException` - anything else is out of scope of the question.